# Can I use JavaScript to pass html to a script tag?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to pass html to a  tag?  For example can I put `$("script.receiver")html("something to go in the script tag");`

Comment: Use `.text()`, not `.html()`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, also, why the downvote?

Comment: Most likely, yes, but it also probably won't work because the script would be executed at page load, which had already passed.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work for already existing scripts, because it was executed already, but you can add new `script`, for example:

```
$("body").append("<script>alert(1)</script>");
```

Comment: Unfortunately the closing script tag within the ""s closes the script.  It doesn't seem to be easily accomplished.